# Delombok using Gradle

Tags: gradle, lombok

As part of our build process we analyse our source code with SonarQube.

One problem with this is that we use Lombok annotations and SonarQube is not handling this very well -- our code needs to be 'delombok'ed.

Delomboked source removed the annotations and replaces the source file with the final code used by the compiler.

This can be done in gradle (see [here](https://github.com/maydesk/modules/blob/master/master/build.gradle)).

Well, in part. Typically an Ant task can be used to delombok source. Code sample below:-

```
task delombok {
        // delombok task may depend on other projects already being compiled
        dependsOn configurations.compile.getTaskDependencyFromProjectDependency(true, "compileJava")

        // Set up incremental build, must be made in the configuration phase (not doLast)
        inputs.files file(srcJava)
        outputs.dir file(srcDelomboked)

        doLast {
            FileCollection collection = files(configurations.compile)
            FileCollection sumTree = collection + fileTree(dir: 'bin')

            ant.taskdef(name: 'delombok', classname: 'lombok.delombok.ant.DelombokTask', classpath: configurations.compile.asPath)
            ant.delombok(from:srcJava, to:srcDelomboked, classpath: sumTree.asPath)
        }
    }
```

The problem I have with this is that I believe I would need a pre-configured ant system (I've yet to get this working).

Another approach would be to use a Maven lombok:delombok plugin (see [here](http://awhitford.github.io/lombok.maven/lombok-maven-plugin/delombok-mojo.html)). However I don't know how to do this and if this would also require a pre-configured environment.

I'm not sure which is the best approach. An approach that does not require a pre-configured build system and can work fully from gradle/gradlew would be preferrable.

The ultimate aim would to have a 'delombok' project task which would essentially perform the following:

```
java -jar lombok.jar delombok src -d src-delomboked
```

**edit**

So i've pretty much got this to work with roughly this snippet:-

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.14.2'
}

task delombok {
    description 'Delomboks the entire source code tree'
    def srcDelomboked = 'build/src-delomboked'
    def srcJava = 'src'

    inputs.files file( srcJava )
    outputs.dir file( srcDelomboked )

    doLast {
        def collection = files( configurations.compile + configurations.testCompile )
        def sumTree = collection + fileTree( dir: 'bin' )

        ant.taskdef( name: 'delombok', classname: 'lombok.delombok.ant.DelombokTask', 
            classpath: configurations.compile.asPath +
                       configurations.testCompile.asPath )
        ant.delombok( from:srcJava, to:srcDelomboked, classpath: sumTree.asPath )


        // Replace current src directory with delomboked source
        copy {
            from srcDelomboked
            into srcJava
        }
    }
}
```

- This first bit ensures that the lombok jar is available to gradle for
  using the delombok ant task.
- Then we configure the source files to
  use.
- Next we setup gradle to use the ant task.
- Finally the copy task replaces the entire source tree with the delomboked version of the code. Obviously this could be removed to suit your needs.

Comment: Have you tried in the Lombok forum? That is likely the best place to get this solved ;). https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/project-lombok

Comment: With 1.16.18 the delombok ant task is defined as a static inner class of class `Tasks`, so the class name in the above ant taskdef needs to be changed to `classname: 'lombok.delombok.ant.Tasks$Delombok'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using an Ant task is fine. No "Ant preconfiguration" should be necessary. Alternatively, you could use a `JavaExec` task to call delombok as in your last snippet. (`JavaExec` doesn't currently support the `-jar` option, so you'd have to name the main class.) Using a Maven plugin from Gradle isn't possible (except for executing Maven with an `Exec` task).

Comment: Is any configuration required to use ant plugins with Gradle? 

I know that lombok.jar contains a ant task which is described [here](http://projectlombok.org/features/delombok.html)

    lombok.delombok.ant.DelombokTask

Comment: No. See the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html) for details.

Answer (score 10):

I think the easiest way to delombok sources with gradle is:

```
task delombok {
    description 'Delomboks the source code'
    ant.taskdef(classname: 'lombok.delombok.ant.Tasks$Delombok', classpath: configurations.compile.asPath,  name: 'delombok')
    ant.mkdir(dir: 'build/src-delomboked') 
    ant.delombok(verbose: 'true', encoding: 'UTF-8', to: 'build/src-delomboked', from: 'src/main/java')
}
```

Comment: Including only lombok.jar into path is enough, i.e.:
`classpath: configurations.compile.filter { (it.name.startsWith('lombok')) }.asPath`. 

Including all 'compile' dependencies into the project can cause problems. If some of 'compile' dependencies are on another project in a multi-project build (e.g. `compile project(':otherproject') ), gradle `:clean` task fails for these project with "Unable to delete file" for the project's jar.

Comment: Also, wrap the `ant.mkdir` and `ant.delombok` lines in a `doLast { ... }` so that they run when (and only when) the task is invoked.  As shown, the _delombok_ task runs unconditionally.

Comment: This solution doesn't work with Gradle 7 or later.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/franzbecker/gradle-lombok

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.franzbecker:gradle-lombok:1.6'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'io.franzbecker.gradle-lombok'
```

UPD: at the moment I quite enough IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3 + Lombok plugin
and the contents build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:+'
}
```