# Lobok @AllArgsConstructor throw exception when app start on Android 4.2

Tags: android, lombok

I have model

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ProductsRequest {
    private String initiatorType;
    private String categoryCode;
```

I have lombok config:

```
lombok.anyConstructor.suppressConstructorProperties = true
lombok.addGeneratedAnnotation = false
```

On android with API 27(Android 7 on real device) all work fine. On android 17(Android 4.2 on emulator) In this line I get error:

```
return restApiFactory.getProductService().getProducts(productsRequest);
```

error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.beans.ConstructorProperties" on path: /data/app/my-1.apk
```

If I change

```
 @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
```

to standart constructors - all work fine

Answer (score 0):

Because I never experienced such issue with ctor-s I encourage you to describe your problem in more detail. I assume the code you manually wrote somehow differs from the code lombok generated. Might be the visibility of methods or some special annotation added.

Using **delombok** feature (https://projectlombok.org/features/delombok) you will expand the annotations to real code. Than you can diff your manually written code and lombok generated code. So you can explore if @java.beans.ConstructorProperties added or not above the code lombok generated. ([Delombok using Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24997441/delombok-using-gradle))

Note: Actually you will have 3 ctor: @AllArgsConstructor, @NoArgsConstructor and @RequiredArgsConstructor is implicitly covered in @Data.

Based on your *lombok.config* file, ctor-s should not have an annotation. Could it be that some of your flavors are missing the *lombok.config* on class path?